# django panda read sql query map parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pandas

I am trying to connect sql server database within django framework, to read sql query result into panda dataframe

```py
from django.db import connections
query = """SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table] WHERE project=%(Name)s""" 
data = pd.read_sql(query, connections[database], params={'Name': input} )
```

the error message I got is 'format requires a mapping'

if I do it something like below, it will work, but I really want to be able to map each parameter with names:

```py
from django.db import connections
query = """SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table] WHERE project=%s""" 
data = pd.read_sql(query, connections[database], params={input} )
```

I was using odbc driver 17 for sql server

Comment: Why not use the Django ORM?

Comment: unfortunately we have to deal with some legacy code, and use ORM will increase a lot of migration work...

Answer (score 0):

you can format at string level and then run pd.read_sql